# How do remove tab bar when navigate away from tabbar view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbar view controller with one tab being a table view. From the table view cell, I want to navigate to another view. However, the whole tabbar shows up on the second view. How Can I remove the tabbar from the second view? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `targetController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true`
[image]